# How to negate a boolean vector?

Tags: boolean-computation

The `!True` returns `False` but how can I negate a boolean vector such as `{True, False, True}`? The exclamanation mark does not work here like this `!{True,False,True}`.

Comment: doing `??Not` shows `Not` is not Listable. If a function `foo` is Listable, then one can write `foo[{....}]`, and then `foo` will automatically by applied to each element in the list. For example, if you do `??Sin` you'll see it says it is Listable. For non-listable functions, you can use Map, as in `Map[Not,{True,False,True}]` or `Not[#] & /@ v` etc... So, the first thing to always check is to do `??` in order to see if a function is `Listable` or not.

Comment: @Nasser: `Not[#] &` can be written more concisely as `Not`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One straightforward way to negate vectors is to use the full form of !, which it `Not`

```
q = {True, True, False};
Not /@ q
{False, False, True}
```

or equivalently `Map[Not, q]`.

Answer (score 8):

[`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html):

```
Thread[!{True, False, True}]
(* {False, True, False} *)
```